# Is a persistent current in a room-temperature superconductor a perpetuum mobile?

Tags: thermodynamics, superconductivity

Persistent currents can be induced in superconductors that have no decay in current over the period of observation withing the measurement errors. (see for example [this book chapter](https://application.wiley-vch.de/books/sample/3527403493_c01.pdf))

I always thought that this is not a true "perpetuum mobile of the third kind", as one has to put in energy to conserve the superconductive properties of the conductor by continually cooling it. But with the advent of the "room-temperature superconductor" recently I am no longer sure if that thought holds.

Is a persistent current in a room-temperature superconductor truly a example of a system where one has eliminated friction and does not have to input any energy? Or is there any hidden energy expenditure needed, that I am just not seeing?

Comment: Temperature doesn't even seem to be the most important point here, as you could e.g. just run your setup in space. So, the "real question" here is actually more general. Or questions. Like, are all the familiar "lossy phenomena" emerge from such apparently lossless (reversible) "building blocks"? How (high) can we build while keeping the lossless property? Or is there a "catch" in the lossless ones already, just our idealized models and measuring abilities are blind to that? Etc.